# Something changed, now 5800 compiler errors from precompiled header

Tags: iphone, xcode, header-files

I apparently changed something in an iPhone Xcode project, and now when it precompiles the headers I'm getting

```
In file included from [...] /Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8,
                 from [...] /UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8,
                 from [...] /UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9:
/Developer/Platforms/[...]/NSObjCRuntime.h:146: error: stray '@' in program
/Developer/Platforms/[...]/NSObjCRuntime.h:146: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'NSString'
```

and then 5800 more errors...

I'm hoping somebody else did this to themselves recently and can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Is this under version control? If so, do a diff like SLaks says. If not, tsk tsk!

Comment: perhaps this is a separate question I should be asking about how to use version control with .xcodeproj files...  the diffs are big and hard to interpret.  Should I have the .pbxuser, .mode1v3, and .pbxproj all under source control, or only some of them?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378399/ for version control info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GIYF:

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-711554.html

Comment: well, I'd found that myself earlier, but I knew I hadn't changed the "compile source as" setting...  So setting it to "Objective-C" instead of "based on file type" did indeed work, but I'm still mystified as to why I would have had to make this change.  Thanks for forcing me to take a second look!

Answer (score 1):

As cdespinosa linked, you're compiling Objective-C as regular C++.

Go into the project settings and change the "Compile Sources As" to Objective-C++

Comment: so what could I have done accidentally to convince XCode to start compiling my .pch file as C instead of Objective-C?

Comment: I don't know; I know nothing about XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Click every file(e.g  .c files) you have in the Xcode navigator. On the right panel, open the Identity and Type view and set the File Type to Objective-C source, this works for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .something long../UIKit.h reference from you project settings for "Prefix Header", replace it with something from your previous projects.