# How to "Version" Your Xcode Code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, version

Sometimes I did some mistake. After that I made some bug and for some reason the program won't run. I want to go back to previous version. How would I do that?

Comment: Don't you use version control (like git, hg or svn)? o0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xCode 4 you can create a local git repository on creating a project. [Look here](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html).
If you are not using xCode 4, you can use external tools for git or svn. Just google for it, you will find a lot of solutions!

Comment: Source Control is a big subject.

Comment: So it's automatic? Looks like I check the text box there. Is git a file or a directory? Where are all the updates located?

Comment: Git is a 'hidden' directory, where files a organized. Basically you can commit changes of you project, which will create a revision. Later on you can switch between this revisions per file base, if needed. To explain it all, the comment box doesn't allow enough characters ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a revision control system.  This is a big topic, so start by reading [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Xcode has support for a few revision control systems.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378399/what-osx-xcode-version-control-system-should-i-use-for-iphone-development) discusses most of them, but [git](http://git-scm.com/) support wasn't available back then (although, personally, I have an irrational hatred of git).